# When I use Aspose WorkbookDesigner to open an excel template file I got a "Error xml namespace" exception

Tags: c#, xml, aspose

I got the same exception in both VS2010 and VS2017 while using .Net FrameWork to open an excel template file.
I'm using App.config to config file path in a C# Console application.

The code is:

```
string filename = "...";
WorkbookDesigner.Open(filename);
```

I'm quite sure filename is correct.
The exception code is

> Aspose.Cells.ExceptionType.InvalidData

and the message is

> "Error xml namespace:http://purl.oclc.org/ooxml/spreadsheetml/main".

Comment: The link you provided is in Japanese and I can't read.  The error is either due to you specifying the wrong filename or the file is not proper xml.

Comment: I figured it out.It is because of file type.I open a .xls file and save it as a .xlsx file then use WorkbookDesigner to open it as .xlsx file,but in fact it is different betweet original file and a "save as" file.When I opened a "save as" file,it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the file type.
I open a .xls file and save it as a .xlsx file then use WorkbookDesigner to open it as .xlsx file,but in fact it is different betweet original file and a "save as" file.
When I opened a "save as" file,it failed.